# Get Max Value In Column Of Unknown Number of Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not very good with Excel at all and I haven't found a specific answer for this. I'm looking for a simple formula to retrieve the max value in a particular column. I need it to begin searching from row 8, so for example =MAX(A8:"?"). I thought it would be * or something like that but it doesn't appear to be. I don't know what the last row is going to be because it will vary. How do I specify the 2nd variable in the formula to be the last row in the column without knowing beforehand?

Comment: This solution locates the value of the last cell in the column which is partly what I need but I'm not quite sure how to dissect it to get just the last non-empty cell location within the column.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a **"Dynamic named range"**. If you have continuous numeric data from A8 downwards then that can be defined as

`=OFFSET($A$8,0,0,COUNT($A$8:$A$1048576))`

[Excel will add in sheet names]

If you name that range Data then you can simply use

`=MAX(Data)`

The DNR may also come in useful for other calculations

In Excel 2007 or later versions You could also convert your data in to a `table` and then you can refer to a specific column of the table which will increase in size as the size of the table increases.

Some information on Dynamic named ranges here: http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Barry's solution, but a little cleaner (in my opinion).

```
=MAX(OFFSET($A:$A,7,0,COUNT($A:$A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but I'd use: =MAX(A8:A1048576)

Comment: Haha yeah I'm looking for ways to avoid this. I didn't think it'd be such a hassle to do something like this with such and advanced application. If I can't find a better solution I'll have to go with this.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way in Excel:

```
=MAX(A8:A1048576)
```

Creating UDF in VBA. This allows for a dynamic offset and will sum the column it is placed in:

```
Function SumColumn(offset As Double)

    Dim Data As Range

    Set Data = Application.Caller.EntireColumn.Resize(Application.Caller.EntireColumn.Rows.Count - offset, 1).offset(offset, 0)

    SumColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Data)

End Function
```